# Refuting a bizarre "proof" that $\sum_{k\geq0} (-1)^k=\frac12$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

Let $g\in C^\infty(\Bbb R)$ and consider $\int g(x)e^x dx$. Integrating by parts, we have:
$$\int g(x)e^x dx= g(x)e^x-\int g'(x)e^x$$
$$=g(x)e^x-g'(x)e^x+\int g''(x)e^x dx=g(x)e^x-g'(x)e^x+g''(x)e^x-\int g'''(x)e^x dx$$
$$=...=\Big[\sum_{k\geq 0} (-1)^k g^{(k)} (x)\Big]e^x$$

Where $g^{(k)}(x)=\frac{d^kg}{dx^k}$

If we let $g(x)=e^x$, we have $g^{(k)}(x)=e^x\ \forall k$ and so:
$$\Big[\sum_{k\geq 0} (-1)^k \Big]e^{2x}=\Big[\sum_{k\geq 0} (-1)^ke^x \Big]e^{x}=\int e^xe^xdx=\int e^{2x}dx=\frac12e^{2x}$$

From which the result follows.

Obviously there is something wrong here as the sum is divergent, but I can't figure out what that is.

Comment: There is a problem with the convergence. So the last term in the first series of equalities is not well justified

Comment: "there is something wrong here" indeed. It is in "$=...=$".

Comment: Where does the integral disappear after $=\ldots =$?

Comment: @kmitov I'm following the idea of summation. Each integral $\int g^{(k)}(x)e^x dx$ decomposes into $g^{(k)}(x)e^x-\int g^{(k+1)}(x)e^x dx$ where the latter integral decomposes in the same way.

Comment: @RhysHughes but the onus is on you to show the error terms disappear (the integrals $\int g^{(k)}(x)e^x\,\mathrm{d}x$) and this is not true in this case

Comment: @AnneBauval while I agree this is likely the error, this comment is unhelpful towards my aim of understanding *why* it is wrong

Comment: This was the error in the alleged *proof*. The "why" (the error in the *result*) is much more blatant: the series cannot be convergent "because" $(-1)^k\not\to0.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using integration by parts you can conclude that $$\int g(x)e^xdx=\Big[\sum_{k\geq 0}^{n-1} (-1)^k g^{(k)} (x)\Big]e^x+(-1)^n\int g^{(n)}e^xdx$$
For $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

If you take the limit $n\to \infty$ on both sides, and assume (crucially) that $(-1)^n\int g^{(n)}e^xdx$ goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$, then you can conclude that $\int g(x)e^xdx=\Big[\sum_{k\geq 0}^{\infty} (-1)^k g^{(k)}\Big]e^x$, but for the case $g(x)=e^x$ the limit $\int g^{(n)}e^xdx$ does not go to $0$, which explains why you got an absurdity.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by the limit of $\int g^{(n)}e^x\,dx$ ? Which antiderivative are you considering ?